Does the equation hold?
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty}Mx(1-e^{-x})^{M-1}e^{-x}\;{\rm d}x\overset{?}{=}\sum_{k=1}^{M}\frac{1}{k}\;,\forall M\in \mathbb{N}_+
$$
or calculate the integral(if correct), then:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{M}\binom{M}{i}\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{i}\overset{?}{=}\sum_{k=1}^{M}\frac{1}{k}\;,\forall M\in \mathbb{N}_+
$$
What does the proof of this equation look like?

In the textbook "Wireless Communication: Principles and Practice (Second Edition)-Theodore S.Rappaport" , chapter 7, I see that it substitutes the integral with the summation, but it doesn't demostrate.

I wounder weather it is correct or not. If it is correct, I would appreciate it very much if you could give the demonstration.
Oops! I find a proof in this paper, in its' Appendix VI, but if you have a better or more concise way to proof it, feel free to share your idea!!!

What do you mean here by derivation?

Sorry for the choice of this word. I have modified the problem. It's just a matter of proving that equation or showing that it's incorrect

The 2nd equation seems to be a special case of Cor. 2.1 in https://doi.org/10.37236/1265

The article you linked mentions that they verified it through induction. I wouldn't call that better, but it might be more illuminating depending on personal sensitbilities.

Substitute in the integral x=log y, dx = dy/y and thereafter z=1-1/y. Compare the result with the integral representations in https://www.emis.de/journals/JIS/VOL15/Sofo/sofo12.html .

Thank you all for your replies!!!

$$M\int_0^\infty x(1-e^{-x})^{M-1}e^{-x}dx\overset{e^{-x}=t}{=}-M\int_0^1\ln t(1-t)^{M-1}dt=-M\int_0^1\ln (1-t)t^{M-1}dt$$
$$=-M\frac{\partial }{\partial s},\bigg|{s=1}\int_0^1(1-t)^{s-1}t^{M-1}dt=-M\frac{\partial }{\partial s},\bigg|{s=1}\frac{\Gamma(s)\Gamma(M)}{\Gamma(s+M)}=-\Gamma(M+1)\frac{\partial }{\partial s},\bigg|{s=1}e^{\ln(\frac{\Gamma(s)}{\Gamma(s+M)})}$$
$$=-\psi(1)+\psi(M+1)=\gamma-\gamma-\sum{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{k+M}-\frac1k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^M\frac1k$$
